# What app is being used in this video?

Tags: windows-10

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y53p1d5P6LA&t=324s&ab_channel=TitusTechTalk
At 1m 25s into this 'Chris Titus' W10 Debloat video, it steps through a PS1 file. What app is being used for this? It doesn't appear to be Powershell or Powershell ISE. Is it a Linux app?

Comment: It appears to be a WSL2 instance within Windows Terminal.  Likely just editing it with whatever bash editor they used.  It’s most definitely Windows Terminal though.

Comment: Ramhound: Thanks for your response. In his videos Chris often states that it's simple to edit PS1 debloat scripts, but neglects to say how it's actually done. Is 'Windows Terminal' included in the latest W10 versions or does it need to be added? I'd like to customize some debloat scripts myself.

Comment: It's a UWP application on the Windows Store.  You would also have to enable WSL2 I would presume.  Windows Terminal isn't a bash editor, it's similar to that of PowerShell or Command Prompt.

Comment: @g-mouse18, the PS1 files are just text files, so you can use whatever text editor you want (such as notepad).  It doesn't have to be the one in the video, unless you really want that one for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

> What app is being used for this?

It's likely `vi` or one of its clones, difficult to identify in a low-resolution video, ran within a WSL2 instance.  They are running the Windows Bash (i.e. WSL2) environment within what I suspect is [Windows Terminal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab).

> Is it a Linux app?

`vi` is indeed a Linux application.